# How do I fight flying, fire-breathing Titan Slugs?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So I was just preparing my fortress for the inevitable siege, but ended up being visited by a Fire-breathing, Flying Titan Slug. I had a slight idea what I was in for, but I definitely didn't expect to lose 81 Dwarves out of the 92 I had. I had prepared as many Dwarves as I could that had some fighting skill, gave them a moment to acquire weapons and armor and had the cannon fodder charge soon followed by my skilled veterans...luckily one cracked open his skull and his own fire burned out his brain. 
[image]

**Is there a way to fight these fire breathing flying titans?** I expect losses, especially with the ability to cause a wildfire to spread through the map, but there has to be a way to avoid this somewhat.

Although, it was a lot fun being surprised like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shields are great against breath attacks, and ranged weapons are great against flying targets, and of course flying won't do them much good if you fight them in 1 z-level high structures. You can minimize losses by making better [armor](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Armor) and providing [danger room](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Danger_room) training to your dwarves, I would not recommend facing titans without at least steel armor/weapons and at least proficient level soldiers. You can also use [traps](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Trap_design) to get rid of them (the sort of traps that involve supports and levers, not just building a weapon trap on a tile), though it may require quite a bit of ingenuity and a sacrificial animal (or migrant!) to lure them into the trap. If you're concerned about fires, fight them where the dwarves are strongest - underground.

Comment: danger room is interesting, might have to try it out. The wiki says traps don't work on Titans, has that been proven wrong?

Comment: @Paralytic If you can cause a cave-in on top of a webbed trap, you can catch Titans (and forgotten beasts). But other than that, you'd need to manually trigger the traps. (Link them to level, put level to repeat)

Comment: @RavenDreamer: You can't attach levers to cage traps.

Comment: @Paralytic no, I meant complex traps. I should make that clearer.

Comment: What about the pathing? I don't seem to be able to target the beast with my military due to smoke. Maybe it's something new in the latest versions (I'm using 40.24)?

Comment: @KurzedMetal you should probably ask a separate question on that issue.